# How to change the name after the @

Tags: gmail, domain

How can you have a Gmail account or any e mail account with a different name? For example `123@anothername.com` instead of `123@gmail.com`? I have already tried going to the account settings and tried using Outlook but all of them require their ending after the `@` sign. I just want to know how to change that because I am starting my own little company and it looks more professional having my company name instead of Gmail or any other ending.

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Please checkout [ask].

Answer (score 9):

You need to purchase your own domain name, e.g. `anothername.com`, from a [domain registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_registrar). Once you've done so, you need to find an email/web hosting service that will enable you to set up email addresses at your domain. As far as I know, any web hosting company will provide this feature, even on their cheapest plans. Many of these services provide you with simple webmail options like SquirrelMail, Horde, or Roundcube, as well as POP/IMAP access to your email so you can use a third-party client like Microsoft Outlook or Thunderbird with your email.

You could also pursue more advanced options like setting up your own server or purchasing a dedicated server, although these options may cost considerably more and involve much more work on your part.

If you want to use the Gmail interface for your business email, look into [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/). Google Apps also provides access to Google Drive, Docs, etc, in addition to Gmail email accounts `@anothername.com`.

Answer (score -1):

Having a custom domain for you email addresses requires that you own a custom domain. You could buy it directly to a domain registrar but you should be prepared to manage it properly. IMHO small business should consider to get the domain from a provider that could help with the domain management tasks.

Regarding Gmail accounts with a custom domain for your business you have to sign up for G Suite Business or G Suite Basic. For further details checkout [Gmail for work](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/for-work/)

It's worth to say that you could use Gmail as your IMAP/POP/SMTP email client. For further details see:

- [Check email from other accounts with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en)
- [Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)